# wpf binding combobox to observable collection

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have an ObservableCollection that gets it's data from a DataTable that is populate from a Postgres Database. I need to bind this ObservableCollection to a ComboBoxColumn in a DataGrid. I have seen quite a lot of examples on how to do this, yet I'm constantly missing something.

Edit: This is the new updated code and it is working except for the INotifyPropertyChanged that I have set only to "name" (yet)

```
namespace Country_namespace
```

{

```
public class CountryList : ObservableCollection<CountryName>
{
    public CountryList():base()
    {

      // Make the DataTables and fill them           



    foreach(DataRow row in country.Rows)
    {
       Add(new CountryName((string)row.ItemArray[1], (int)row.ItemArray[0]));
   }           
    }
}

public class CountryName: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private int id_country;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public CountryName(string country_name, int id)
    {
        this.name = country_name;
        this.id_country = id;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set {
        name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CountryName");
        }
    }

    public int idcountry
    {
        get { return id_country; }
        set { id_country = value; }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

}

XAML:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Country_namespace"

<Windows.Resources>
<c:CountryList x:Key="CountryListData"/>
</Windows.Resources>
```

DataGrid Column:

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="country">
                                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CountryListData}}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: "Datacontext should bet set to the ObservableCollection country_" This might be incorrect.

Comment: No I have not implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. And that is one of the reasons I am asking this question. I am completely puzzeled when it comes to ObservableCollections as I have never used them before.

Answer (score 0):

first of all. you can just bind to public properties.

country_ seems no public property.

second if binding not work you always have to check datacontext first and binding path second. you can use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to do this at runtime

EDIT:

you did not post your itemssource for your grid. so some assumptions here.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
  ...
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MySourcePropertyForCountries}"/>
```

--> this would work when your MySource object item has a public property MySourcePropertyForCountries.

but if your want to bind your combobox to a list wich is outside the MySource object. then you have to use some kind relativeSourcebinding or elementbinding.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grd" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
  ...
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=grd, Path=DataContext.MyCountries}"/>
```

--> this would work when the datacontext of the datagrid has a property MyCountries

Comment: The itemssource for my grid is a different datatable.

Comment: well then you have to use elementname binding or relativesource binding to walk up to your datacontext wich has the Mycountries property. using StaticResource is also an option

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I already edited my question and posted the code, that kinda worked for me.